# How to define universal function for bit setting in C++?

Tags: c++, embedded, bit-manipulation, microcontroller, volatile

I have got following problem in C++. I have a variable which is a pointer to a mcu peripheral register

```
uint32_t volatile * ctrl_reg;
```

I have defined a function for bit setting in given 32 bits word. This function is intended to be used not only for setting bits in peripheral registers but also in common 32 bits variables.

```
uint32_t bitMask(uint8_t bitPos)
{
    return 1UL << bitPos;
}

void setBit(uint32_t *word, uint8_t bitPos)
{
    *word = *word | bitMask(bitPos);
}
```

My problem is that as soon as I call

```
setBit(ctrl_reg, enable_bit);
```

the compiler warns me that pointer to `volatile uint32_t` is not compatible with pointer to `uint32_t`. I see but I don't know how to resolve my issue in clean manner i.e. how to use common function for bits setting in registers and also in common variables. Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `volatile` is used wrong here. The contents of the `ctrl_reg` is volatile, the pointer would be a fixed HW address.

Comment: Notwithstanding the comment by @πάνταῥεῖ, you can just add the `volatile` qualifier to the function argument: `void setBit(uint32_t volatile* word, uint8_t bitPos)`.

Comment: @Adrian Shouldn't it be something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bee54c71a709f9f) (don't be bothered by the seg fault)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, on MSVC and clang-cl, the ordering of the `*` and the `volatile` qualifier *seems* to make no difference ... I can mix and mingle them as I see fit. Dunno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply *don't* write bloatware for to hide away simple and readable bit manipulations.

`ctrl_reg |= 1u << n;` is already super-fast and super-readable. This code *cannot* be improved. Every C programmer can see what it does with a quick glance,  it's as canonical as code gets.

The only kind of improvement possible is to use named bit masks, such as:

```
#define CTRL_FOO (1u << 5)
#define CRTL_BAR (1u << 6)
...
ctrl_reg = CRTL_FOO | CTRL_BAR;
```

More info about how to access/declare hardware registers here:
[How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/q/276290)

Answer (score -1):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>


template<class T>
uint32_t bitMask(T bitPos)
{
    return 1UL << bitPos;
}

template<class T>
void setBit(uint32_t *word, T bitPos)
{
    *word = *word | bitMask(bitPos);
}

int main()
{
    {
      uint32_t j = 2;
      uint32_t * ctrl_reg = &j;
      std::cout <<"\n"<< j;
      for(uint32_t enable_bit = 2; enable_bit < 8; enable_bit++)
      {
          setBit(ctrl_reg, enable_bit);
      }
      std::cout <<"\n" << j;
    }
  
    {
  
      uint32_t j = 2;
      uint32_t * ctrl_reg = &j;
      std::cout <<"\n" << j;
      for(uint64_t enable_bit = 2; enable_bit < 8; enable_bit++)
      {
          setBit(ctrl_reg, enable_bit);
      }
      
      std::cout <<"\n" << j;
    }
  
}
```

output:

```
2
254
2
254
```